# Pandas add new second level column to column multiindex based on other columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a DataFrame with column multi-index:

```
System   A                B
Trial    Exp1    Exp2     Exp1    Exp2
1        NaN     1        2       3
2        4       5        NaN     NaN
3        6       NaN      7       8
```

Turns out for each system (`A, B`) and each measurement (`1, 2, 3` in index), results from `Exp1` is always superior to `Exp2`. So I want to generate a 3rd column for each system, call it `Final`, that should take `Exp1` whenever available, and default to `Exp2` otherwise. The desired result is

```
System   A                       B
Trial    Exp1    Exp2    Final   Exp1    Exp2    Final
1        NaN     1       1       2       3       2
2        4       5       4       NaN     NaN     NaN
3        6       NaN     6       7       8       7
```

What is the best way to do this?

I've tried to use `groupby` on the columns:

```
grp = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1)
```

And was thinking of using either `transform` or `apply` combined by `assign` to achieve it. But am not able to find either a working or an efficient way of doing it. Specifically I am avoiding native python `for` loops for efficiency reasons (else the problem is trivial).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshape, add column with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and then reshape back by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) + [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = df.stack(level=0)
df['Final'] = df['Exp1'].fillna(df['Exp1'])
df = df.unstack().swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
System    A               B           
Trial  Exp1 Exp2 Final Exp1 Exp2 Final
1       NaN  1.0   NaN  2.0  3.0   2.0
2       4.0  5.0   4.0  NaN  NaN   NaN
3       6.0  NaN   6.0  7.0  8.0   7.0
```

Another solution with [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) for select `DataFrames`, create new `DataFrame` by [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html), but there is missing second level - was added by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) both `DataFrames` together:

```
a = df.xs('Exp1', axis=1, level=1)
b = df.xs('Exp2', axis=1, level=1)
df1 =  a.combine_first(b)
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.columns, ['Final']])
df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
System    A               B           
Trial  Exp1 Exp2 Final Exp1 Exp2 Final
1       NaN  1.0   1.0  2.0  3.0   2.0
2       4.0  5.0   4.0  NaN  NaN   NaN
3       6.0  NaN   6.0  7.0  8.0   7.0
```

Similar solution with `rename`:

```
a = df.xs('Exp1', axis=1, level=1, drop_level=False)
b = df.xs('Exp2', axis=1, level=1, drop_level=False)
df1 = a.rename(columns={'Exp1':'Final'}).combine_first(b.rename(columns={'Exp2':'Final'}))
df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
System    A               B           
Trial  Exp1 Exp2 Final Exp1 Exp2 Final
1       NaN  1.0   1.0  2.0  3.0   2.0
2       4.0  5.0   4.0  NaN  NaN   NaN
3       6.0  NaN   6.0  7.0  8.0   7.0
```

Comment: This is pure genius! Thank you!

Comment: Glad can help, I add explanation in second.

Answer (score 2):

- `stack` with your first level of the column index `stack(0)` leaving `['Exp1', 'Exp2']` in the column index
- Use a `lambda` function that gets applied to the whole dataframe within an `assign` call.
- Finally, `unstack`, `swaplevel`, `sort_index` to clean it up and put everything where it belongs.

---

```
f = lambda x: x.Exp1.fillna(x.Exp2)
df.stack(0).assign(Final=f).unstack() \
    .swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(1)

     A               B           
  Exp1 Exp2 Final Exp1 Exp2 Final
1  NaN  1.0   1.0  2.0  3.0   2.0
2  4.0  5.0   4.0  NaN  NaN   NaN
3  6.0  NaN   6.0  7.0  8.0   7.0
```

---

Another concept using `xs`

```
d1 = df.xs('Exp1', 1, 1).fillna(df.xs('Exp2', 1, 1))
d1.columns = [d1.columns, ['Final'] * len(d1.columns)]
pd.concat([df, d1], axis=1).sort_index(1)


     A               B           
  Exp1 Exp2 Final Exp1 Exp2 Final
1  NaN  1.0   1.0  2.0  3.0   2.0
2  4.0  5.0   4.0  NaN  NaN   NaN
3  6.0  NaN   6.0  7.0  8.0   7.0
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to choose one answer...sorry. And I like your assign() very much! Really appreciate it.

Comment: stack / unstack is inefficient for large dataframes

Answer (score 0):

doesnt feel super optimal but try this :

```
for system in df.columns.levels[0]:
    df[(system, 'final')] = df[(system, 'Exp1')].fillna(df[(system, 'Exp2')])
```

Comment: Thx @Steven, though I forgot to mention I was able to accomplish this using loops. But I'm trying to explicitly shun away from `for` statements as it beats the purpose of Pandas...

Comment: Don't forget sort_index, as the new columns will be appended to the very last.